# SQL query selecting non unique entries ordering by unique

Tags: sql

My SQL server sample table have two columns ID and Date where ID is not unique.

```
ID  Date
1   1/1/2022
2   1/1/2021
3   1/1/2020
1   1/1/1999
```

I want to select the most recent n entries with unique IDs together with all entries matching those IDs so for example

```
for n=1:
1   1/1/2022
1   1/1/1999
```

and

```
for n=2:
1   1/1/2022
1   1/1/1999
2   1/1/2021
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this ?

I think I may need a self join but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why your n=1 example did not return most recent 1 entry for each id? (but returned 2 most recent entries for id:1, and nothing for id:2). Is it meant to say return all rows for id if the number of rows for that id =n?

Comment: No what I mean is first find the n recent matches by taking only the most recent out of each bunch of matching IDs. But then for each result add all other entries with matching ids. Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `RANK()` function to find the top N most recent `ID`s, then use that result as a subquery.  For example, your `n=2` query would look like this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Date) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, Date
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM cte WHERE rnk <= 2)
ORDER BY ID, Date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this is more efficient than a join (of some sort) ?

Comment: I don't know the join query to which we would be comparing, but adding an index on `(Date, ID)` should make my answer even faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER window function to order and find the best of each id, then use Top N with ORDER BY to filter for the TopN ids, and then self join to get all entries for those ids:

```
select *
from Tbl T
     inner join
     (  select top 2 *   --<<< This is 'N'
        from
           (
          select ID, Date
          from (
                select id, Date, row_number() over (partition by id order by Date desc) as RN1
                from Tbl
               ) S1
          where S1.RN1=1
          ) as BestOfEachId
        order by Date desc
    ) TopN
    on T.id=TopN.ID
```